# Since i switched from RVM to Rbenv, i cannot deploy my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, capistrano

I switched from rvm to rbenv. My app has not changed, however i had to download again ruby and all of the gems.
Since that my deployment fails. It seems it's when the remote server try to do git clone and ask for the password :

```
executing "git clone -q admin@92.243.18.178:/folders/folders/releases/20130716125555 && cd /folders/folders/releases/20130716125555 && git checkout -q -b deploy f8b7206995a83600be40061fb675685b28c3e1db && (echo f8b7206995a83600be40061fb675685b28c3e1db > /folders/folders/20130716125555/REVISION)"
    servers: ["95.142.171.17"]
Password: 
    [95.142.171.17] executing command
 ** [95.142.171.17 :: out] admin@92.243.18.178's password:
Password: 
 ** [95.142.171.17 :: out]
 ** [95.142.171.17 :: out] Permission denied, please try again.
 ** admin@92.243.18.178's password:
Password: *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /folders/folders/releases/20130716125555; true"
```

The problem is that the git repo is on the same computer using the same account. Here is the log of ssh :

```
Jul 16 14:48:14 rn-outils sshd[28172]: Accepted password for admin from 88.185.158.43 port 51917 ssh2
Jul 16 14:48:14 rn-outils sshd[28172]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user admin by (uid=0)
Jul 16 14:48:22 rn-outils sshd[28324]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=rn-outils  user=admin
Jul 16 14:48:25 rn-outils sshd[28324]: Failed password for admin from 92.243.18.178 port 56744 ssh2
```

I checked the history of deploy.rb and nothing has changed for a long time.

I do not understand how a reinstall of capistrano may have affected it's capability to perform git clone. What can i do to have capistrano acting as before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never managed to make it work as before. Using a public key to ssh into production without using a password does not trigger the problem, so i have added all the dev public keys to the authorized keys of my server.